# Function to be called after dom is loaded / ready - activate the right accordion tab

Tags: jquery, .net, sharepoint

I'm trying to run a script from server-side, but the DOM isn't ready.

I want to activate the right accordion "tab"

```
function ValidateTermStoreProperties(index){
    $('#myProfileSettings').accordion('activate', index);
}
```

I've tried to use .ready() without any luck! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you mean 'run the script server side'? Javascript can only be run on the client-side.

Comment: Show us how you're using `.ready()`

Comment: If it is ASP.NET, try to use Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to register you script. Don't forget to wrap it with jquery $(document).ready.

Comment: @Tariqulazam Yes I'm using Page.ClicentScript.RegisterStartupScript . I'll try to wrap it inside document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string activateAccordin = "$(document).ready(function(){$('#myProfileSettings').accordion('activate', 1);});"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeOf(Page),"ActivateTab", activateAccordin, true);
```

Try this.